# Send POST using retrofit2

Tags: android, post, retrofit2

So, I am new to Retrofit2. I am trying to send the signup data.

**JSON response is**

```
{
"status": "success",
"status_code": "200",
"data": [
    {
        an array of user data
    }
  ]
}
```

**Request Interface**

```
public interface RequestInterface {

@POST("aNet/rest")
Call<ServerResponse> operation(@Body ServerRequest request);
}
```

So, I have used [POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create the necessary [code](https://pastebin.com/Xpz9cVaf).

But i cannot understand how do i send the data. Can someone help me? A simple tutorial is not enough as they do not help me with my problem.

**EDIT 1**

As suggested I will add a few more code. 
Model User

```
public class User {
@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("status_code")
@Expose
private String statusCode;
@SerializedName("data")
private List<Datum> data = new ArrayList<>();

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getStatusCode() {
    return statusCode;
}

public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
    this.statusCode = statusCode;
}

public List<Datum> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<Datum> data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

Class Datum

```
public class Datum { //All the values like setname, setemail, etc;}
```

So the difficulty i am facing is how do i send use the model to send the data.
Its a pretty stupid question.

Comment: please insert code here!

Comment: Why do you say that the tutorial does not solve the problem? Your case is such a common one that the tutorial should tell you everything. Follow for example http://square.github.io/retrofit/ and replace their service with yours

Comment: Are you sure that "status" and "status_code" are returned in the JSON?

Comment: you can figure the example here https://futurestud.io/tutorials/tag/retrofit

Comment: @kdblue I have added the code. I hope now toy can understand my situation

Comment: Can you please put the code of class ServerRequest?

Comment: You also need to make sure all variables in Datum and User exactly match the json.

Comment: @ShaneMonksO'Byrne I have used postman to retrieve the JSON and POJO to create the class files. My problem is with how to send the data